# FrameLayout not correctly constrained. Bottom part of it gets hidden under BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-constraintlayout, bottomnavigationview

I have this layout for my activity which uses multiple fragments that have RecyclerView in it. The FrameLayout here is the container for the fragments. The problem is that, although I set my FrameLayout's bottom to the top of BottomNavigationView, last element of RecyclerView gets hidden under BottomNavigationView.

My code for activity layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:logo="@drawable/money_icon"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Code for fragment includes RecyclerView:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/dark_gray"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/finishedSlipsRecycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Screenshot of the problem:

[image: Screenshot of the problem:]

Comment: are the other fragments working fine?

Comment: @AlanDeep no, they have the same problem.

Comment: are you changing height or width programmatically in your app? or using some kind of animation?

Comment: @AlanDeep no, not at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually raised due to RecyclerView flows over FrameLayout. The better definition and the answer of the problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61859576/recyclerview-flows-over-the-screen/61859609#61859609)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the issue is because of this line:

`app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"`

Just remove it and everything will be fine.

#### EDIT:

Replace your `ConstraintLayout` in

> Code for fragment includes RecyclerView:

by `FrameLayout` since it only contains one element. I think there's a problem with putting the `ConstraintLayout` inside `FrameLayout` like this.

Comment: Actually, that line didn't even exist. I just added that while I was trying answers I found on internet and forgot to remove it. Therefore, removing that line is not solving my problem.

Comment: What if my ConstraintLayout had multiple elements? Which is actually the case but I removed those elements to keep the question simple

Comment: Just try to see if the problem is from `ConstraintLayout`, if it is then we will find out a solution